# performance issue about 'while + read' .vs. AWK

Tags: performance, bash, awk, while-loop

I had meet a strange problem . I have a large file (maybe more than 1,000,000,000 lines) which contains only a single column which represent the size of file . It looks like

```
55568
9700
7243
9692
63
5508
1679
14072
.....
```

And I wants to count the occurences of each value. I use two different script

NOTE:: the file used below is cutted ,only contains 10,000 lines !!!

```
bob@bob-ruby:~$ cat 1.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read size ; do

      set -- $size

     ((count[$1]++))

done < file-size.txt
bob@bob-ruby:~$


bob@bob-ruby:~$ cat 2.sh
#!/bin/bash

awk '{count[$1]++}' file-size.txt
bob@bob-ruby:~$
```

and I found that 1.sh (pure shell script) is much slower than 2.sh (awk-script)

```
bob@bob-ruby:~$ time bash 2.sh

real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.032s
bob@bob-ruby:~$ time bash 1.sh

real    0m0.618s
user    0m0.508s
sys     0m0.112s
bob@bob-ruby:~$
```

Through 'strace' command , I found 1.sh generated lots of syscall , while the '2.sh' is much less , why is that ?

Is that the 'awk' do some 'magic' work  inside ?

```
bob@bob-ruby:~$ strace -c bash 1.sh
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 38.62    0.042011           1     30320           rt_sigprocmask
 29.97    0.032597           2     20212           _llseek
 15.33    0.016674           2     10115           read
 12.57    0.013675           1     10106     10106 ioctl

 (cut)


 bob@bob-ruby:~$ strace -c bash 2.sh
 % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
 ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  95.52    0.008000        4000         2         1 waitpid
   3.20    0.000268          21        13         5 access
   1.28    0.000107           5        21           fstat64
   0.00    0.000000           0         9           read
```

Comment: Why is this strange? Shell scripts aren't exactly known for their performance (they are slow).

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, what would `cat file | sort | uniq -c` take timewise?

Comment: I had read the ABS Guide , it told us use pipe as less as possible ,

Comment: these scripts do not even produce any output to check. May be awk is just optimizing out the computations

Comment: @favoretti, since OP is so concerned about the pipe operator, you could save one of the two by eliminating the useless use of cat and just saying `sort -n | uniq -c`

Comment: I'd be interested to see your timings by eliminating the use of `set -- size`, and just use `((count[$size]++))`. In any case, while I applaud your interest in differences in performance, you should expect to see these sort of differences. Your `strace` output shows you the exact differences. There's not much more to be said. Good luck to all!

Comment: 'set -- $size' command do it's work entriely in the memory , without any IO consumption . I had removed the 'set' command in 1.sh , it doesn't change the result

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Chet Ramey(chet.ramey@case.edu)

On 12/21/12 9:59 PM, boblin wrote:

> hi, chet :
>
> ```
> I had meet a strange problem . I have a large file (maybe more than
> ```
>
> 10,000 lines) which contains only a single column which represent the size
>   of file . It looks like
>
> ```
> 55568
> 9700
> 7243
> 9692
> 63
> 5508
> 1679
> 14072
> .....
> ```
>
> And I wants to count the occurences of each value. I use two different method
>
> ```
> bob@bob-ruby:~$ cat 1.sh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> while read size ; do
>
>       set -- $size
>
>      ((count[$1]++))
>
> done < file-size.txt
> bob@bob-ruby:~$
> ```

This is really an inefficient way to do it, but not so much that it should
make huge difference.  There's no need to use `set' just for cosmetic
reasons.  You can do

while read size; do
((count[$size]++))
done < file-size.txt

> ```
> bob@bob-ruby:~$ cat 2.sh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> awk '{count[$1]++}' file-size.txt
> bob@bob-ruby:~$
> ```
>
> and I found that 1.sh (pure shell script) is much slower than 2.sh (awk-script)
>
> ```
> bob@bob-ruby:~$ time bash 2.sh
>
> real    0m0.045s
> user    0m0.012s
> sys     0m0.032s
> bob@bob-ruby:~$ time bash 1.sh
>
> real    0m0.618s
> user    0m0.508s
> sys     0m0.112s
> bob@bob-ruby:~$
> ```
>
> Through strace command , I found 1.sh generated lots of syscall , while the
>   '2.sh' is much less , why is that ?

Because you didn't trace awk.  You traced bash invoking and waiting for
awk.  That's why `waitpid' dominated the execution time.

> Is that the awk do any 'magic' work  inside ?

awk has many fewer restrictions on its operation, as explained below.

> ```
> bob@bob-ruby:~$ strace -c bash 1.sh
> % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
> ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
>  38.62    0.042011           1     30320           rt_sigprocmask
>  29.97    0.032597           2     20212           _llseek
>  15.33    0.016674           2     10115           read
>  12.57    0.013675           1     10106     10106 ioctl
> ```

There is an issue with bash invoking sigprocmask a lot, because it invokes
setjmp in such a way that setjmp saves and restores the signal mask.  I
did some work on signals and traps that will allow the next version to
avoid restoring the signal mask.

The lseeks and reads have to stay.  I imagine awk can read as much data as
it wants into an internal buffer and process it from memory.  The shell is
required to reset the file offset back to what it has consumed after each
read, so programs it invokes can get the intended standard input -- it is
not allowed to read ahead between read builtin invocations.  That means
the shell has to test the file descriptor it's reading from for the
ability to seek each time the read builtin is run -- terminals and pipes
can't seek backward in the data stream, so the shell has to read one
character at a time from those.  The shell's read builtin does some minimal
buffering, so even for regular files where the shell can seek backwards,
it has to call lseek to adjust the file pointer before the read builtin can
return a line.  That also increases the number of read(2) calls required:
in some cases, the shell reads the same data from the file more than once,
and at least one read(2) call is required per invocation of the read
builtin.

The ioctl is to tell whether or not the input fd is attached to a
terminal; in addition to unbuffered reads, several options are only
available when using a terminal.  There is at least one lseek per call
to the read builtin, to tell whether the input fd is a pipe.

That accounts for the system calls you listed in your strace output.

### Chet

`The lyf so short, the craft so long to lerne.'' - Chaucer`
Ars longa, vita brevis'' - Hippocrates
Chet Ramey, ITS, CWRU    chet@case.edu    http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/~chet/

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference is that the `while` loop version is required to read the file one line at a time and `awk` reads *the input* <strike>the entire file</strike> and parses it in memory.  You are lucky that `read` is a builtin or it would be considerably less efficient.  The usual case for shell scripts is that each `while` loop iteration spawns multiple child processes to process a line.  They can be considerably slower - consider parsing a line into fields using the following:

```
while
  read line
do
  field1=`echo $line | cut -f 1 -d '|'`
  field2=`echo $line | cut -f 2 -d '|'`
  ...
done
```

I inherited a shell script that processed database output this way.  My manager was amazed when I turned a multi-hour batch process into about 20 minutes with a simple chunk of `awk`.

**Edit**
I dug into the [awk source code](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/index.html) because I was curious about this one.  It looks like this is a simple usage of the Standard IO buffering hidden behind a simple call to `getc`.  The C Standard Library implements efficient buffering on the input stream.  I ran `dtruss` using the following very simple shell script

```
#!/bin/zsh
while
    read line
do
    echo "$line"
done < blah.c
```

The input, *blah.c*, is a 191349 byte C file containing 7219 lines.

The `dtruss` output contained 4266 calls to `read` with a buffer size of 1 byte for the shell script.  It looks like `zsh` is not buffering its input at all.  I did the same test using `bash` and it contained precisely the same sequence of `read` calls.  Another important note is that `zsh` generated 6074 system calls and `bash` generated 6604 system calls.

The equivalent `awk '{print}' blah.c` command showed 56 calls to `read_nocancel` with a buffer size of 4096.  It had a total of 160 system calls.

---

The easiest way to think about this is that `awk` is a program that parses text for a living and shells are concerned with process management, plumbing together pipelines, and generally interactively running programs for a user.  You should use the appropriate tool for the job at hand.  If you are processing data from large files, steer clear of general purpose shell commands - that is not what the shell is meant to do and it will not do it very efficiently.  If you are writing scripts that are executing shell utilities back to back, then you wouldn't want to write it in perl or python because it will be painful handling exit statuses of subprocesses and pipelining between them.

Comment: the file is huge (6GB) , the physcial mem is 8GB . when I run the AWK script , it seems that it only consume not much Mem (<10MB)

Comment: <10MB sounds right. You're only increasing memory as you add a new element to the `count` array. Good luck to all.

Comment: but @D.Shawley saids : 'awk reads the _entire_ file and parse it in memory.' . I know that the while-loop is so slow because it causes so much 'read' syscalls . But how can the AWK just makes only 9 'read' calls?